How to log all Java exceptions on creation?
In some cases exceptions being thrown are causing crashes in native library that we use before they get to be logged anywhere. So waiting for UncaughtExceptionHandler to log them won't work. Even exceptions that were eventually caught caused crashes in native code in a few cases. And crash logs generated have no info on these exceptions.
Is there any way to log all exceptions as soon as they are created? Preferably it needs to work in a release build, without attached debugger.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58325793/21105992 <- implement your own java.lang.Throwable class?

Perhaps you should explain in more detail about "causes crashes in native library". How does throwing an exception do that?

You don't want to do it. There are many exception thrown and caught in libraries. Even in  SDK.

You should fix the bugs in the native library, for sure. It should not crash due to some exception being thrown, not to speak of exceptions throw and caught somewhere (which suggests that they are entirely unrelated to the native library).

@holger it's when they go from Java into native code, break something there, then flow back into Java code where they are caught

@maxpovver This does not change the fact that the bugs in the native library should be fixed rather than wasting time with the symptoms.

If you know what methods are called from native code you can add try catch in them.
You don't need to do it manually if you use some AOP library.
